# Prove that if $a$ is a root of $fg$, $a$ is a root of $f$ or $a$ is a root of $g$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain, $f, g \in R[x], a \in R$. Prove that if $a$ is a root of $fg$, then $a$ is a root of $f$ or $a$ is a root of $g$.

My attempt (**edited**):

pf. Let $R$ be an integral domain, $f, g \in R[x], a \in R$. If $a$ is a root of $fg$, then $fg(a)$ = 0. Since $R$ is an integral domain, a nonzero non-unit $r \in R$ is irreducible if for all $a, b \in R$ such that $r = ab$, either $a$ or $b$ is a unit. Hence if $a$ is a root of $fg$, $b$ must be a unit. Thus, $b^-1 \in R$ and so $b^-1fg = abb^-1$. Hence, $a = b^-1fg$. Thus, $fg \vert a$ so $a$ must divide $f$ or $g$.

I am not too sure about the last couple of statements. Would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: I'm sorry to say your proof is way off.  You may want to check the definition of what it means for an element $c \in R$ to be a root of a polynomial $h$ in $R[x]$.

Comment: So, $2$ is a root of $f(x)=x^2-x-2$. What do you conclude?

Comment: From the point $a |fg$, which makes no sense, you have not done anything right.

Comment: @TedShifrin $f(2)$ = 0.

Comment: Well, sure. You are supposed to conclude more. Say something about factors of $f(x)$.

Comment: may be we can see this like , given $(fg)(a)=0 \implies f(a)g(a)=0$ now the given ring is integral domain so in integral domain of $ab=0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$ so from this either $f(a)=0 $ or $g(a)=0$ i.e either $a$ is root of $g(x)$ or $a$ is root of $f(x)$

Comment: Unfortunate choice of letters, @TheStudent :)

Comment: @TedShifrin If $f(x)$ = ($x$ - 2) and $g(x)$ = ($x$+1), then either $f(a)$ = 0 or $g(a)$ = 0. In this example, $f(a)$ = 0.

Comment: I think I would do a proof by contradiction.  Suppose, $f(a)\ne 0, g(a) \ne 0$ and $f(a)g(a) = 0.$  Is this consitent with $R$ being an integral domain?

Comment: @Doug M Would I need a proof by contradition? After stating that $fg(a) = 0$, can't I simply state "Since $R$ is an integral domain, $f(a)g(a)$ = 0. Hence, either $f(a)$ = 0 or $g(a)$ = 0. Therefore $a$ is a root of $f$ or $a$ is a root of $g$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a \in R$ is a root of

$f(x)g(x) \in R[x], \tag 1$

then

$f(a)g(a) = fg(a) = 0; \tag 2$

now if

$f(a) \ne 0 \ne g(a), \tag 3$

then since $R$ is an integral domain we have

$f(a)g(a) \ne 0; \tag 4$

but this contradicts (2); thus (3) is false and hence

$f(a) = 0 \; \text{or} \; g(a) = 0; \tag 5$

that is, $a$ is a root of at least one of $f(x)$, $g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Would I necessarily need a proof by contradition though? After stating that $fg(a)$ = 0, could I simply state "Since $R$ is an integral domain, $f(a)g(a)$ = 0. Hence, either $f(a)$ = 0 or $g(a)$ = 0. Therefore $a$ is a root of $f$ or $a$ is a root of $g$."

Comment: @yagayeet:  your argument is fine;  *reductio ad absurdum* is not necessary.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Let $R$ be an integral domain, $f,g\in R[x],$ $a\in R.$ If $a$ is a root of $fg,$ then $fg(a) = 0.$ Since $R$ is an integral domain, a nonzero non-unit $r\in R$ is irreducible if for all $a,b\in R$ such that $r=ab,$ either $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

All of this is fine.

> Hence if $a$ is a root of $fg$, $b$ must be a unit.

A stylistic comment: at this point, you haven't defined what $b$ is, but you start talking about it as if your reader will know what it is. How does $b$ relate to $f,$ $g,$ and $a$? You defined what it means for an element $r\in R$ to be irreducible in general, but now you seem to be applying it without explaining what you're assuming is irreducible.

> Thus, $b^{−1}\in R$ and so $b^{-1}fg = abb^{-1}$. Hence, $a=b^{-1}fg$.

Where did the equation $b^{-1}fg = abb^{-1} = a$ come from? This is equivalent to saying that $fg = ab,$ which was not an assumption at any point of the problem. Remember that at the beginning of the problem, we assume that $fg(a) = f(a)g(a) = 0$ (remember also that if $p\in R[x]$ is a polynomial and $r\in R,$ then $p(r)$ does not mean $p\cdot r$ (the product of the polynomial $p$ and the constant polynomial $r$) but rather the evaluation of $p$ at $r$ (what you get when you replace all the $x$'s in $p(x)$ with $r$'s).

> Thus, $fg\mid a$ so $a$ must divide $f$ or $g$.

Indeed, $a = b^{-1}fg$ implies that $fg$ divides $a.$ However, to conclude from this that $a$ divides $f$ or $g$ requires that $a$ be a prime element, which again is not an assumption of the problem. Moreover, even if you could conclude that $a$ divides $f$ or $g,$ this does not show that $a$ is a root of $f$ or of $g,$ because the definition of $a\in R$ being a root of $f$ is not that $a$ divides $f,$ but rather that $f(a) = 0.$

In order to actually prove the statement, you should proceed as described in Robert Lewis' answer. Either try a proof by contradiction assuming that $a$ is not a root of $f$ or $g,$ so that $f(a)\neq 0$ and $g(a)\neq 0$ and then use the fact that $R$ is an integral domain to conclude that $fg(a)\neq 0,$ so that $a$ is not a root of $fg$ (contradiction!).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your thorough answer. When I posted my question, I started off by saying "If $a$ is a root of $fg$, then $a \vert fg$." Shortly later after @Ted Shifrin commented I changed that statement to: "If $a$ is a root of $fg$, then $fg(a) = 0$." Thus, the latter statements do not make sense.